# Newbie: ternary "if" condition syntax on VIEW

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to have the if condition logic like:

```
var == 10 ? “10″ : “Not 10″
```

on Rails VIEW. What I tried is following:

```
<%= session[:id]=="out"? link_to "Sign in", login_path : link_to "Sign out", logout_path%>
```

I know it looks odd, and unsurprisingly it does not work. So, if I would like to use ternary if condition on VIEW, what is the correct way to do in my case?

**---------One more condition---------**

I would like to have **two** "link_to" in **else** condition

-----The error message I got--------

```
compile error

syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
...ession[:id]=="out" ? link_to "Sign in",
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this (the only diffrence is a space between `"` and `?` and the use of parentheses)

```
<%= session[:id]=="out" ? link_to("Sign in", login_path) : link_to("Sign out", logout_path) %>
```

Altough parentheses are optional in Ruby they are needed to maintain operator precedence in some cases.

IMHO ternary operators are hard to read. You could also do something more verbose:

```
<%= link_to("Sign in", login_path) if session[:id] == "out" %>
<%= link_to("Sign out", logout_path) if session[:id] != "out" %>
```

Comment: +1 ended up using <%= "outputtext" if a=b %> syntax instead, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
session[:id]=="out"?
```

looks wrong. It should be

```
session[:id]=="out" ?
```

By the way if you need more link in the else part switch to an if else. It could be more clean:

```
<% if condition %>
  link
<% else %>
  link
  link
<% end %>
```